# confuse to make error message in PHP

Tags: php, sql

all this code is work, what left is I try to echo a message if query not find anything..

```
include("config.php");

$search = $_POST['search'];  

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM barangtbl WHERE nama LIKE '%$search%' ") or die(mysql_error());  
  while ($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {  
    echo $res['nama'].'<br>';  
  } 


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)) {
  while ($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {  
    echo $res['nama'].'<br>';  
  } 
}
else
{
 echo "Not found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if($sql)
{
    echo  "success";
}
else
{
    echo  "Error";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
include("config.php");

$search = $_POST['search'];  

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM barangtbl WHERE nama LIKE '%$search%' ") or die(mysql_error());  
if(mysql_num_rows($sql))
{
  while ($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {  
    echo $res['nama'].'<br>';  
  } 
}
else
{
   echo "The query resulted in an Empty Set";
}
```

Here,
mysql_num_rows($sql) will output the total no of rows in the result. If the query's output is zero rows, the value of mysql_num_rows($sql) is zero which will lead to the if condition being false and hence executing the else part.

Answer (score 0):

John V is right.

But i would suggest you to use mysqli instead of the deprecated mysql function
(deprecated since version 5.5)

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php